# Angular Dart and form validation

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Angular JS has the `$pristine`, `$dirty`, `$valid`, and `$invalid` booleans for checking the state of a form. Are there equivalents for these in Angular Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same properties will be in AngularDart, but since we are still not v1.0, we still have some missing features. This is in the works: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/372

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find anything about this yet too.

**EDIT**

This is available and seems to work fine.